# Jsoup selector basic Android

Tags: android, jquery, parsing, android-studio, jsoup

I'm trying to learn jsoup for android and I'm having a hard time with learning the selectors. I've already set up the application with simple buttons and textviews that can retrieve basic info i.e. title etc.  Now I'm trying to get the text that I've highlighted below.  I've tried multiple times and cannot get the correct syntax down.

```
<li class="info info info">
<script>clicked = false</script>
<div class="simple">
    <p class="name"><a href="http:/falselinky.com">TEXT I NEED TO PARSE</a>       </p>
    <ul class="Type">
                    <li>Normal</li>        </ul>
    <p class="address">120 Hollywood Blvd.</p>
</div>
<div class="sortables">
    <p class="inches"></p>
        </div>
<div class="action_links">
                                                                </div>
```

Comment: You say "I've tried multiple times and cannot get the correct syntax down". Please include your most recent try in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/index.html").get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Throws exception
}
Element simple = doc.getElementsByClass("simple").first();
Element p = simple.getElementsByClass("name").first();
Element a = p.select("a").first();
String text = a.text();

System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Ok. I've gotten the nullpointerexception gone.  Now, that code snippet that you provided works well.  However, this example I provided happens multiple times on the page source, and I need to return a list of all the names. How would I go about iterating this over a for loop?

Comment: `for(Element simple : doc.getElementsByClass("simple")){...}` :-)